# read.xlsx takes a very long time and tons of memory

Tags: r, macos, memory, rjava, r-xlsx

I'm trying to load an .xlsx file into R that has one sheet and is about 31 MB in size.

I run the following

```
options( java.parameters = "-Xmx6g" )
require(xlsx)
yt = read.xlsx("big_spreadsheet.xlsx",1)
```

and I get nothing. My system monitor program shows that the allotted memory slowly fills up and then just stays full. I haven't let it run for hours but ten minutes should be sufficient, especially when I could have just loaded into Numbers (I'm on Mavericks) and saved it as a CSV in that time.

Yes, I have much more than 6 GB of memory. 2 GB doesn't seem to be enough and yields the error:

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I did, however, make the mistake of letting the `rJava` package install its own version of Java. I downloaded JDK 8 after the fact but I have no idea how to check if this is being used.

So why does it take 6 GB of RAM to (fail to) load a 31 MB file? Can I fix this somehow?

Comment: R support for xlsx is quite horrific. Unless you have a really good reason to read in xlsx directly, it is much easier, faster, and more efficient to re-save your files as a .csv/equivalent in Excel.

Comment: I had this problem before, and used `RODBC` with the Excel ODBC driver instead.

Comment: have you tried the XLconnect library instead of xlsx? I have had good experiences with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never got this to work. I've lately been using the [`readxl`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=readxl) package for reading from Excel spreadsheets, which has no Java dependency and seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

yes, use **readxl** package,since xlsx package require java that takes a loads of time to load and chances are more that it will return error on reading a file of mere size(even of 2mb)

Its very simple to use just write

```
   read_excel("path")
```